# How to get the contentOffset of a UIScrollView mid-scroll?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll

How would one get the contentOffset or similar information about a UIScrollView while the user is still scrolling? For example if I wanted to place an image as a header right above the content of a UIWebView, without the image being part of the WebView's scrollView, but have it update while the user scrolls, not just jumping to the position after they let go. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5, the `UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property which is the `UIScrollView` responsible for handling the scrolling. Prior to iOS 5 you can search the `UIWebView`'s subviews property for the subview using `[subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]`.

Once you have the `UIScrollView`, you can then set its delegate property. In the delegate you can then respond to the `scrollViewDidScroll:` message when the user scrolls, and update the position/contents of your header view.

Added: 29/2/2012 - In order to preserve the `UIWebView`'s functionality, you will need to forward your intercepted `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to the `UIWebView` too.  To do this, you can call the UIWebView at the end of all mandatory methods within the protocol and implement something like `forwardInvocation:` or `forwardingTargetForSelector` for the optional protocol methods.  This will preserve your original `UIWebView` behavior and allow you to enhance it with your own logic.

Comment: when I implement this, I can get the contentOffset as described, but the zooming is messed up. I commented out "webview.scrollView.delegate = self;" and the zooming was fixed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Greg As I said in my answer, you can't do this with a `UIWebView`. If you set yourself as the delegate for the `UIWebView`'s `UIScrollView`, then you're stomping on the `UIWebView`. It can't be done.

Comment: Then forward all delegate calls to the webview itself after doing what you need to do. I.e. keep your self as delegate, and then in the delegate methods send the same message and parameters to the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just put the header as a separate view above the `UIWebView`? Why does it have to be a subview?

Comment: It doesn't. I don't know where you're getting that from.